# How does clojure bind variable parameters?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop, clojure-core.logic

I am a newbie in Clojure.The problem originated when I once checked the source code of `conj`:

```clj
    (def conj 
      (fn ^:static conj
        ([] [])
        ([coll] coll)
        ([coll x] (clojure.lang.RT/conj coll x));4
        ([coll x & xs] ;1
         (if xs ;2
           (recur (clojure.lang.RT/conj coll x) (first xs) (next xs)) ;3
           (clojure.lang.RT/conj coll x)))))
```

The source code of `conj` shows that it uses recur to implement the function. This source code looks very simple. 
What I'm confused about is the condition it uses when determining whether recursion needs to continue. It looks like it checks if the variable parameters  is `nil` , but if the variable parameters  is `nil`, it will soon be equivalent to the third "arity" of `conj`?
I then tried to evaluate the following expression:

```clj
user=> (conj [] 1 (next []))
[1 nil]
user=>
```

It works normally and successfully adds `nil` to the vector. I understand that clojure actually wraps `nil` in a list and passes it to the function, but I don't understand why `recur` can pass a real `nil` in ? And why does clojure recognize and match the correct "arity"?

---

```
user=> (def my_conj
   (fn [coll x & xs]
     (println "xs is" xs)
     (if xs
       (recur (clojure.lang.RT/conj coll x) (first xs) (next xs))
       (clojure.lang.RT/conj coll x))))
#'user/my_conj
user=> (my_conj [] 1 (next []))
xs is (nil)
xs is nil
[1 nil]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, my apologies for not realizing earlier that you have come across an aspect of Clojure behavior that I had never seen before.  Today I learned something new about Clojure, and given 10 years with it, that surprised me.

This is mentioned in a couple of sentences of the official Clojure documentation for recur, here: https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#recur

Here is a page of community-written examples and documentation (so not "official") that describes this behavior of recur with functions that have variadic arguments: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/recur#example-55ff3cd4e4b08e404b6c1c7f

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making a copy of this function, changing its name to something else, and adding some calls to `println` of the values of whatever interests you, e.g. x, xs, etc, and watch what gets printed in a Clojure REPL session when you call your function with different parameters that interest you.

The `if xs` is true if the value of `xs` is any value at all other than `nil` or `false`.  The value `(nil)` is a list of one element, and is considered true when used as an `if` conditional expression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I actually tried to do this before posting this question, and the result is the same as described in the question.

Comment: `(next [])` evaluates to `nil`, so your example call `(my_conj [] 1 (next [])))` is the same as if you had called `(my_conj [] 1 nil)`.

Comment: Also I do not know if this is confusing, but clojure.lang.RT/conj is a call to a Java method, not a recursive call.

Comment: `(recur (clojure.lang.RT/conj coll x) (first xs) (next xs)) ;3` Isn't this a recursive call?And it should be simplified to:`(recur result (first xs) nil)`,`result` is the evaluation result of `(clojure.lang.RT/conj coll x)`, `nil` is `(next xs)` because `xs` contains only one element: `nil`.

Comment: One more thing, which I am not 100% certain about, but I believe is true: When you call conj/my-conj with exactly 2 arguments, it looks as if Clojure could call either the version declared with parameters `[coll x]` or `[coll x & xs]`, but it appears to always call the one declared with `[coll x]` in that case, when called from outside.  However, the `recur` call will never switch between different declarations -- it will always call the definition with the same arity, no matter what.  I believe that is a limitation/property of `recur` in Clojure.

Comment: I agree with this, but I don't understand how Clojure binds a variable parameter to a `nil`, because if you call it from the outside, you will only get one `(nil)` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The part of the function declared with parameters `[coll x & xs]` means "bind the value of the first parameter to coll, bind the value of the second parameter to x, then if there are no more parameters, bind xs with the value nil, otherwise bind xs with the value that is the list of the remaining parameters".

You can see this with this simpler function that does not use recur at all:

```
user=> (defn my-fn [a & xs]
         (println "a=" a " xs=" xs))

user=> (my-fn 1)
a= 1  xs= nil

user=> (my-fn 1 2)
a= 1  xs= (2)
```

Comment: But how to evaluate this form: `(recur (clojure.lang.RT/conj coll x) (first xs) (next xs)) ;3`?Unlike your example, `recur` really declares additional parameters! If you use this example to explain it, it may end up being evaluated as `(recur (clojure.lang.RT/conj coll x) (first xs)) ;3`. Because the last parameter is "nil", it will not be passed. I think it makes sense to explain this, maybe `recur` did something,but I can't find other information to prove it..